# How to get the request value in the Symfony2 custom validator

Tags: php, symfony, customvalidator

I have a custom validator in Symfony2 and I would like to get one of the submited values from my form.

When vardumping the $value from

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
```

I can see the variable I need, but the result is too big in order to be able to find where is my request parameter placed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to this problem:

1. I created a new field in my entity that does not exists in the database, but exists in the form.
2. In the validator class, I am accessing all the entity values, and also this new one that I need.

FYI, in order to access all the entity object in the validator, you need to put:

```
public function getTargets()
{
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
}
```